# MySQL latest post by date

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, max

I have 3 tables:

```
member
member_id|member_name

training_member
training_id|member_id

training
training_id|team_id|training_date
```

I need to find the latest training, with team_id and training_date for each member.
If the member haven't got any trainings it should return NULL as team_id and training_date

I've tried a lot of different ways, like this:

```
SELECT m.member_id, t.team_id, MAX(t.training_date)
FROM member m
JOIN training_member tm ON m.member_id = tm.member_id
JOIN training t ON tm.training_id = t.training_id
GROUP BY m.member_id
ORDER BY m.member_name, t.training_date DESC
```

It doesn't give the correct result though, it seems to return the first team_id listed and not the one associated with MAX(training_date)

What do I need to change?

EDIT:
sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1ec1/1

Comment: can you post sqlfiddle?

Comment: Sure, here you go:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1ec1/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly something like this:-

```
SELECT m.member_id, Sub2.team_id, Sub2.MaxTrainingDate
FROM member m
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT tm.member_id, t.team_id, Sub1.MaxTrainingDate
    FROM training_member tm 
    INNER JOIN training t ON tm.training_id = t.training_id
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT tm.member_id, MAX(t.training_date) AS MaxTrainingDate
        FROM training_member tm 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN training t ON tm.training_id = t.training_id
        GROUP BY tm.member_id
    ) Sub1
    ON Sub1.member_id = tm.member_id
    AND Sub1.MaxTrainingDate = t.training_date
) Sub2
ON Sub2.member_id = m.member_id
ORDER BY m.member_name, MaxTrainingDate DESC
```

Uses an inner select to get the latest training per member, joins that against the training member and training tables to get the other details (ie, team_id), then LEFT JOINs that against member (to cope with members who have had no training).

EDIT - removing the sub queries and putting them into views to allow the main SQL to be a views.

View to get the max training date for each member

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `vw_max_training` AS select `tm`.`member_id` AS `member_id`,max(`t`.`training_date`) AS `MaxTrainingDate` from (`training_member` `tm` left join `training` `t` on((`tm`.`training_id` = `t`.`training_id`))) group by `tm`.`member_id`;
```

View to get the team details for the max training date per member

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `vw_max_training_team` AS select `tm`.`member_id` AS `member_id`,`t`.`team_id` AS `team_id`,`sub1`.`MaxTrainingDate` AS `MaxTrainingDate` from ((`training_member` `tm` join `training` `t` on((`tm`.`training_id` = `t`.`training_id`))) join `vw_max_training` `sub1` on(((`sub1`.`member_id` = `tm`.`member_id`) and (`sub1`.`MaxTrainingDate` = `t`.`training_date`))));
```

Final view

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `vw_main` AS select `m`.`member_id` AS `member_id`,`sub2`.`team_id` AS `team_id`,`sub2`.`MaxTrainingDate` AS `MaxTrainingDate` from (`member` `m` left join `vw_max_training_team` `sub2` on((`sub2`.`member_id` = `m`.`member_id`))) order by `m`.`member_name`,`sub2`.`MaxTrainingDate` desc;
```

Comment: This gives the correct result!
But... As I need to use it in a view, I get: "View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause"

Comment: Try converting each subselect to a stand alone view, then use the views in the selects instead. Will edit my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
SELECT * FROM member LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT training.training_id,team_id,max(training_date) as training_date, 
member_id FROM training LEFT JOIN training_member ON 
training.training_id = training_member.training_id GROUP BY member_id) a 
ON member.member_id = a.member_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to return `null`  If the member haven't got any trainings.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT m.member_id, t.team_id, max(t.training_date)
FROM member m
LEFT  JOIN training_member tm ON m.member_id = tm.member_id
LEFT  JOIN training t ON tm.training_id = t.team_id
GROUP BY tm.member_id
ORDER BY m.member_name, t.training_date DESC
```

**Demo :**   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1ec1/42

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't give the correct result, see new fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9e747/2

Comment: It will unless, if any of the `training_id` of table `training_member` is not present in `team_id` of table `training`. In the above sql fiddle you added `training_id` 7 which is not present in `team_id` of `training` table, so it's returning unexpected results.

Comment: An issue here is that the value of t.team_id may come from any of the training done by m.memberid, not necessarily the training that corresponds to the max training date .

Comment: @Kickstart Agreed..+1 for your solution:)